# The nonexistence of any "good" norm on $\ell^\infty(\mathbb R)$

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces

I'd like to prove by counterexample that there is no norm on the space of all real-valued bounded sequences such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|f_n - f\| = 0$ is equivalent to $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = f$. In other words, I want to find a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb N} \subset \ell^\infty(\mathbb R)$ which converges to $f$ (pointwise) but for which
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \|f_n - f\| \neq 0.
$$

This question is inspired by the paper [A Note on Pointwise Convergence](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1951-002-01/S0002-9939-1951-0040647-7/S0002-9939-1951-0040647-7.pdf), which proves that pointwise convergence is not "metrizable" on $\mathcal{C}[0,1].$ I haven't been able to find any proofs that this result holds in the space of bounded sequences, but since the space is not even complete under any norm by Baire, I'm quite sure a counterexample exists. I'd really appreciate any ideas y'all have.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ usually denotes the space of *all* sequences. Your question seems to be about the space of bounded sequences, which I would usually write as $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What about $f_n(i)=\delta_{n,i}$ and $f(i)=0$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner This works for some norms but not for others, e.g. this sequence does converge w.r.t. the norm $(x_n)_{n \geq 1} \mapsto \sum_{n \geq 1} \lvert x_n \rvert / 2^n$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk:  Thanks; I see now, OP wants it for all norms

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Thanks, I wasn't sure what the standard name for the space was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\lVert \bullet \rVert$ be any norm on $\ell^\infty$. For each $i \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\delta_i$ be the Kronecker delta sequence (that is, $\delta_i(j) = 1$ if $i = j$, and $\delta_i(j) = 0$ if $i \neq j$).

Define $f_i = \frac{1}{\lVert \delta_i \rVert} \delta_i$, so that $\lVert f_i \rVert = 1$ for all $i$. Then $f_i \to 0$ pointwise, but

$$\lVert f_i - 0 \rVert = 1$$

does not converge to $0$.

Comment: So I was on the right track by thinking of $\delta$

Comment: Yes! Sorry if my comment above seemed critical, you had the exact right idea, it just needed a little scaling :)

Comment: No offense was taken

Comment: Just to make sure I get it, $f_n \to 0$ pointwise because if we pick any $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and and we let $n$ be larger than $x$, then $f_n(x) = 0$ right?

Comment: Exactly right! [character limit]